# On storing a binding in an Observable object in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, data-binding

I am creating a Mac-App. When it is launched multiple times all windows should access the *same* application-state (`theAppState`) but each window should display its own data (of kind `MyClass`).

As is shown below, when the `MainWindow` creates the `MyClass`-object it passes the binding to `theAppState`.

The `MainWindow` has a button that invokes `obj.incBoth()`.  As a result, `theAppState` is *increased* (as it should).

The body shows `theAppState` in the different ways:

1. `self.appState` is displayed *correctly* and it is increased on each button press.
2. `obj.appstate` is **not** displayed correctly (the original value **42** is always shown)
3. `obj.appstate()` is  **not** displayed correctly (same as obj.appstate)

Please help me understand this strange behaviour!

**Update:** Notice that both the view and the `MyClass`-object (obj) can access `theAppState` via their local bindings. In the view, `self.appState` returns the *correct* value and the object prints out the *correct* value in `incBoth()`. The thing I find strange is that the view cannot access theAppState *indirectly* via `obj.appstate2()`. Your comments suggest that one should not use a binding in a `StateObject`. This may be correct, but it does explain the strange behaviour.

```
import SwiftUI

class MyClass : ObservableObject {
    @Published var x = 0
    @Binding var appstate : Int
    
    init(appstate : Binding<Int> ){
        self._appstate = appstate
    }
    
    func appstate2() -> Int {
        return self.appstate
    }
    func incBoth() {
        x+=1
        appstate += 1
        print("x=\(x) appstate=\(appstate)")
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    @Binding var appState : Int
    @StateObject var obj : MyClass
    
    init(appstate: Binding<Int>){
        self._appState = appstate
        self._obj = StateObject(wrappedValue: MyClass(appstate: appstate))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("appState = \(appState),  obj.appstate = \(obj.appstate), obj.appstate2 = \(obj.appstate2())   obj.x = \(obj.x)")
        Button("Inc") {
            obj.incBoth()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct ProblemApp : App {
    @State private var theAppState = 42
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView(appstate: $theAppState)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Binding`s are not supposed to go in an `ObservableObject`. Why are you putting `appState` in `MyClass` in the first place? That is not necessary for achieving "all windows should access the same application-state but each window should display its own data".

Comment: @Sweeper, I did consider to use AppStorage, but the data I need to store is too complex (it is a Set),  and I don't need persistency. Is there a third way to achieve the objective that all windows should access the same state?  I also like to understand *why* obj.appstate returns an old value.

Comment: How is `AppStorage` relevant? What I don't understand is, why are you putting `appState` in `MyClass`? Why not just access `appState` with the `@Binding` in `MainView`? Or just send it as an `environment`/`environmentObject` so that every subview has access to it?

Comment: @Sweeper,  `MyClass` must have access to `theAppState` (but it does not need to be an observer).

Comment: Okay, how about wrapping `theAppState` in an `ObservableObject` and pass that to `MyClass`? The views should still use a `@Binding`/`@ObservedObject` to observe changes to `theAppState`.

Comment: Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) . It is as simple as copy and paste into your code.
Note, `@Binding` is **only** for use in `Views` not classes.

Comment: `Binding` is only for SwiftUI `View` if an `ObservableObject` has something that it depends on it is best to use some architecture and introduce something like Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you want some logic relaced to the app state, so the the `@State` can just be a struct then you can put logic in funcs, e.g.

```
struct TheAppState {
    var x = 42

    mutating func inc() {
        x += 1
    }
}
struct ProblemApp : App {
    @State private var theAppState = TheAppState()
```

In SwiftUI, state is designed to be decentralised so you need to be careful to only put related vars in the struct and not global ones. Otherwise `body` won't be called as efficiently as normal.

In  SwiftUI, in general try to avoid custom classes because that will lead to consistency problems Swift's use of structs is designed to eliminate.

Comment: I did consider to use `AppStorage`, but the data I need to store is too complex (it is a `Set<Int>`), and I don't need persistency.  Also, even if AppStorage solves the problem I still like to understand the things I mention in the **update**.

Comment: The issue is an object consistency problem, that's why swiftUI uses structs to prevent that!

Comment: I edited my answer with something you can try

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  I tried, no difference.